# "Inlet" and "Intake": Synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Currrently both [inlet](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inlet) and [intake](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intake) have a fair amount of questions. Neither had a tag wiki and the questions on both seem to have the same subjects. Is there any reason they shouldn't be made synonyms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On this [NASA page](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/inlet.html) on inlets it says:

> In England, inlets are called intakes, which is a more accurate description of their function at low aircraft speeds.

So it depends on SE's manual of style, I'm not sure if it's been discussed before, but I think AmE is used for tags (e.g. [horizontal-stabilizer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizontal-stabilizer) with a z). In this case intake, despite being more descriptive, can be the synonym.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I'd really say they are the same. They are used interchangeably, but "intake" generally makes me think of an engine, whereas "inlet" makes me think of a smaller opening for something else, like for the a/c packs or something. Inlet sounds odd for the engine intake. The suffix "-let" is a diminutive, usually indicating a smaller version of something else. Like "piglet" or "winglet." I've heard people use "inlet" for engines, but it doesn't sound right to me.

Interesting side note: I found out from @mins that "winglet" is basically the English equivalent of the French "aileron."

Comment: You have a good point from the language perspective but in my experience it would be the other way around.

Comment: @fooot I see it on here a lot, but it never sounded right to me